# How to call a function when an action is selected for particular records in tree view

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I want to directly call a function in `Action` when some records are selected in tree view.I tried like this:

**Python**

```
@api.multi
def od_reconfrim_call(self):
    inbound_ids = self._context.get('active_ids', False)
    sheet_line_id = self.env['abc.inbound'].browse(inbound_ids)
    if sheet_line_id:
        ids = [(6,0,[line.id for line in sheet_line_id])]
        for line in sheet_line_id:  
            print "hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii"
            print "hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii"
```

**XML**

```
<record id="action_reconfirm" model="ir.actions.act_window">
<!-- <record id="action_reconfirm" model="ir.actions.server"> -->
    <field name="name">Reconfirm</field>
    <field name="res_model">abc.inbound</field>
    <!-- <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field> -->
    <!-- <field name="view_mode">form</field> -->
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_abc_inbound"/>
    <field name="state">code</field>
    <field name="code">self.od_reconfrim_call()</field>
</record>

<record model="ir.values" id="action_reconfirmed_add">
    <field name="name">Reconfirm</field>
    <field name="key2">client_action_multi</field>
    <field name="value" eval="'ir.actions.act_window,' +str(ref('action_reconfirm'))" />
    <field name="key">action</field>
    <field name="model">abc.inbound</field>
</record>
```

But it doesn't goes to the function.What to do?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Code is only possible in server actions. So why did you comment the correct action model out?

Comment: @CZoellner I tried by uncommenting `<record id="action_reconfirm" model="ir.actions.server"> ` . But whenever I click `Reconfirm` button in `Action` , call is not calling and it is going to a new `Form View`.